# Is the [rage] tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see that we've recently gained [rage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rage) as a new tag.  It feels to me like it's both:

- **too specific**, as it's a tag for one specific character ability, and
- **too general**, as it could be for any game with a rage ability, even though different games might use the concept very differently.

If I had to make a decision on my own, I'd get rid of the tag.  Thankfully, there's a whole community of more knowledgeable people than me here.

Is [rage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rage) useful?

Comment: related reading: [Do we want a total-party-kill?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5935/23970)

Answer (score 13):

We don't have enough information yet to say.

Tagging on the Stack Exchange is an "emergent folksonomy," which means we let tags grow as the community sees a need and we don't curate tags until an actual problem crops up--then we fix that particular problem.

I'm not seeing any problem with [rage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rage) yet, so let's wait and see how it does.

Answer (score 7):

There is presently one question tagged [rage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rage): unsurprising as it is a new tag. Searching for "rage question", there are 113 questions across a multitude of systems that could benefit from it. There is a smaller number of hits from [sneak-attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sneak-attack), another class feature, but all of these are associated with [dnd](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd) or [pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder). If [sneak-attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sneak-attack) merits a tag, [rage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rage) certainly does.

Comment: It seems like the question then becomes: "Do any specific class features deserve their own tag?"

Comment: @SoldierofVol not really - that would be a different question

Comment: I noticed you went out and tagged some questions with *rage*.  I am slightly concerned about this; Is it your intention to tag all of the 113, or are the 8 you tagged the only ones you think are fitting the tag?

Comment: @Tritium21 only the ones I got around to ... So far

Comment: Update: today, we have 70 of these. most of them dnd5 or pathfinder.